# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)^x\right)^2$

Tags: limits

I've tried to make it into the form $\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x\right)^{-2}$, which would give the value of the limit as $1/e^2$, but wolfram alpha says that it should be zero? Where is the mistake? Thanks for help.

Comment: No, you're correct. I'm not sure what Alpha's problem is (rounding problems?). On a different note, welcome to Math SE! You might wish to take a look at this short [tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/about) of the site.

Comment: Missing parenthesis in your try? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Lim%5B%28%28x%2F%281%2Bx%29%29%5Ex%29%5E2%2Cx%2CInf%5D

Comment: Your 'mistake' is that
$$\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x\right)^{-2} = \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{-2x} $$
and not
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{-x^2}$$
Ie you have to decide if you want compute
$$\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)^{x^2}$$
or 
$$\left(\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)^x\right)^2$$

Comment: @gammatester you're right - it was a simple mistake indeed. Could you give me a hint on how to solve the one with x^2? Should I use logarithms and d'Hospital's Rule? BTW Thanks for help to you all

Comment: Hint:
$$\left(\frac{x}{x+1} \right)^{x^2}= \left(\frac{x+1-1}{x+1} \right)^{x^2} = \left(1-\frac{1}{x+1} \right)^{x^2}\sim_\infty e^{-x}\left(e^{\frac{1}{2}}+ O(\frac{1}{x})\right)
$$
therefore the limit is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your evaluation of the limit is correct as written.  I think you got an incorrect using Wolfram|Alpha because you were not careful with explicitly specifying precedence.  If you typed

```
Limit[(1 + 1/x)^-x^2, x -> Infinity]
```

you will get $0$, because it is evaluating $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{x} \right)^{-x^2}.$$